# VS2008->VS2013 upgraded solution can no longer run tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We've upgraded a VS2008 solution to VS2010 and then to VS2013 Pro. In VS2013 it all builds, but the unit tests all fail with the same error:

> The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or read the
>   data.

The folder structure has not changed, and the test data files are all there in the correct location.

Here's a typical test:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"Autoscribe.Utility.Test\TestData\GetParameters1_RetrievesCorrectParameters.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", @"|DataDirectory|\Autoscribe.Utility.Test\TestData\GetParameters1_RetrievesCorrectParameters.xml", "test-record", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[TestMethod(), Description("String extensions")]
public void GetParameters1_RetrievesCorrectParameters()
{
    // Get test data.
    string input = TestContext.DataRow["input"].ToString();
    string[] outputs = TestContext.DataRow["outputs"].ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // etc
}
```

In VS2008 there was a wizard to set the test properties to connect the test data file to the test, and using this often fixed this class of problem,but this doesn't seem available in VS2013 Pro. Can someone tell me:

a) how to connect a test to a data file in VS2013 Pro without having to explicitly type the DataSource attribute, and

b) any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to explicitly select the original testrun config. It seems the upgrade does not carry this forward.